# Remove cookies before postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

How to remove cookies from client site after post-back.

I have written the following code in my web config but is not working.

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true"/>

<authentication mode="Windows">

  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="Login.aspx" name="MyCustomAuthentication" requireSSL="true" path="/" timeout="60"/>

</authentication>
```